# Zscaler Client Connector Exit Password

Tags: zscaler

Can anyone help me with a sample log generated when a user submits the Exit Password on Zscaler Connector?

I am trying to create a notification (not rely on Zscaler Admin console) when the client is exits.

Thanks

Not able to find any document in Zscaler that touches this topic

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is already included in the latest ZCC version. There is a new feature to force to input a password when a user exits the app with a popup.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).